# Why Prahlad Friedman's hand called dead againist Ted Bort on WSOP 2010?

Tags: rules, wsop

First of all, watch this video;

- [WSOP ME Controversial Hand - Friedman vs Bort (2010)](https://youtu.be/iHQRQNa2CVY?t=341)

I really don't understand why Friedman's hand called dead. He said "call" in his last second exactly but the man who has charge called "dead" his hand.

Is there any wsop rule to support this hand called "dead"? It looks like a valid "call" to me.

Comment: Link is dead https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMESk7wpryo.   Unfortunately there are not clear standards on count down.

Comment: @paparazzo Updated the link, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a lot of controversy around that hand. I think the official explanation from the floorman and supervisor was that as soon as the floorman said "one" the hand was dead. He said "hand dead" a second later, but the time was up when the said "one"....

I think this explanation is pretty thin. Friedman said "call" before the words "hand dead" were pronounced so he should have been allowed to make the call.

Here is a piece on Pokernews on the incident: http://www.pokernews.com/news/2010/09/the-wsop-on-espn-world-champions-november-niners-and-one-ver-8830.htm

Comment: This was an absolutely terrible decision, and a pathetic excuse. The dealer looked like he was afraid to speak up and tell the floorman that Friedman had called, which he clearly heard if the floorman didn't. It's not the dealer's job to make decisions, but it IS his job to inform the floorman of all the relevant facts he may have missed, and he clearly failed. Too bad poker tournaments don't use "instant replay".

Comment: @Lee he?  (the dealer looks female to me...)

Comment: Been a long time since I'd seen it, but I remember the important details.

Comment: The pokernews article "confirms" that the hand should be dead when the count hits one. That's goofy.  Why would "one" be the number where it's dead and not zero? One implies that he still had one second to act, and that's plenty of time to say call.